# Solve sixth degree complex polynomial

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

I am trying to solve this equation
$$ \lambda^6+2\lambda^4+\lambda^2-s^2=0, $$
where $s=1+i\rho$.

with some manipulations I can get
$$ (\lambda^3+\lambda -1-i\rho)(\lambda^3+\lambda+1+i\rho)=0 .$$

So $\lambda^3+\lambda -1-i\rho=0$ or $\lambda^3-\lambda +1+i\rho=0$. But I can't get the roots of each polynomial.

I accept any suggestion, hint or book to read.

Another option is to properly define $s=s(\rho)$ such that the polynomial has "pretty" roots, but I can't think in other definitios for $s$.

Comment: WolframAlpha spits out a mess of cube roots and fractions for both. There is a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#General_cubic_formula, but that's what is causing the mess.

Comment: Yes @JoshuaWang, WolframAlpha has an answer, but for example, if $s=i(\rho^3-\rho)$ then the polynomial have roots of type: $\lambda=i\rho$

Comment: Cardano's method works well here. As you have complex constant terms, the necessary square roots and cube roots will involve complex numbers. You do need to work out  useful expressions for $\sqrt z$ and $\sqrt[3] w$ with complex $z,w$

Comment: For reduced cubic $y^3+3py=2q$, we may write $y_k=2\sqrt{p} \sinh
\left(
  \dfrac{1}{3} \sinh^{-1} \dfrac{q}{p\sqrt{p}}+\dfrac{2k\pi i}{3}
\right)$ where $p>0$.  This may be well-defined in complex domain for most CAS.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \lambda^6+2\lambda^4+\lambda^2-s^2=0
\quad=(λ^3 + λ - s )(λ^3 + λ + s)$$

For each cubic, a single known-real root can be obtained from the cubic equation.

$$x=\sqrt[\Large{3}]{\biggl(\frac{-b^3}{27a^3 }+\frac{bc}{6a^2}-\frac{d}{2a}\biggr)+\sqrt{\biggl(\frac{-b^3}{27a^3}+\frac{bc}{6a^2}-\frac{d}{2a}\biggr)^2+\biggl(\frac{c}{3a}-\frac{b^2}{9a^2}\biggr)^3}}\\
+\sqrt[\Large{3}]{\biggl(\frac{-b^3}{27a^3 }+\frac{bc}{6a^2}-\frac{d}{2a}\biggr)-\sqrt{\biggl(\frac{-b^3}{27a^3}+\frac{bc}{6a^2}-\frac{d}{2a}\biggr)^2+\biggl(\frac{c}{3a}-\frac{b^2}{9a^2}\biggr)^3}}-\frac{b}{3a}$$

where $\quad a=1\quad b=0,\quad c=1\quad d=\pm1$

There is also a [Trigonometric solution for three real roots](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Trigonometry/The_solution_of_cubic_equations)